# Multi-level analysis in SPSS?

Tags: multiple-regression, spss, multilevel-analysis

I am struggling to work out how best to analyse a large set of data in repeated measures design.

I have 4 main conditions: a, b, c, d. Then within each condition, participants repeat a trial 2 times in 3 conditions (so 6 times overall). So there are 24 trials per participant.

Additionally, I have measured the following for each participant:
age, weekly alcohol consumption, weight

I basically want to see the effect of the main conditions on task performance, but need to control for the effect of the 3 task conditions, and other participant information...

Do I run this through a multiple regression analysis? Or hierarchical regression analysis? Or something else?! I am using SPSS.

Thanks!

Comment: Questions about how to use SPSS are off topic here. So you may want to emphasize that this is a statistical methods question and that the software aspect is secondary.

Answer (score 1):

You want the linear mixed models procedure for [example](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/spss/library/spssmixed/mixed/mixed_diet_intro.htm).  These models are complex and you have some work ahead of you.  If you only have to do this once, you might want to hire someone to do it for you.

Comment: what is your main condition ?